# How to struct cleanup code?

Tags: c++, c

We are developing application in a platform whose compiler doesn't support exception in C++ language.

When we call API we need to check the error code from the return result. Sometimes we need to do some cleanup when error happen. We define an macro CHECK_ERROR_GOTO to check error code. So the code like this.

```
int res = callAPI1();
CHECK_ERROR_GOTO(res, cleanup);
A* object1 = callAPI2();    // HERE WE WILL GET ERROR, 
                             //BECAUSE GOTO SKIP INITIALIZATION OF OBJECT1
CHECK_ERROR_GOTO(object1 == NULL, cleanup);
C* object2 = callAPI3(object2);
CHECK_ERROR_GOTO(object2 == NULL, cleanup)
return 0;
cleanup:
    //Cleanup code here.
    delete object1
    delete object2
```

As the code show, we will get object1 initialized skipped by goto, so we need put `object1` and `object2` in the header of function, which is bad because we should put it in the place we need to use. And add {} to create local scope doesn't work, because the cleanup code need to using the local variable.

So anyway we can arrange the code, so we doesn't need put variable initialize in the begin of function?

Comment: note: the `return` statement should be after the cleanup part (unless somehow you return those objects... as it is, it looks like a mem leak now)

Comment: How I envy you having to deal with this absolute abomination.

Comment: The code is missing some semicolons.

Comment: why don't you want to have them variables initialized at the beginning of the function? Seems like a strange requirement?

Comment: @DaanTimmer say you have ten variable, the initialized variable segment code make it hard to understand, the big segment code doesn't have any value to help you understand the function logical.

Comment: the linux kernel has the coding style that objects are destroyed in reverse order of initialization and cleanup of each object has its own label. possibly the macro doesn't do much more than `if (!condition) goto cleanup;`

Comment: Putting all your variables in the beginning of the function is not all that bad. C language was originally such that you had to do it, and it was the standard at the time.

Comment: Ok, I think I can using auto object do clean up, even this is not always possible if the cleanup code is complex. Then I doesn't need goto cleanup, just return is enough.

Comment: @ZijingWu if you have that many initializers and a that big function you are probably doing something wrong. As a guideline functions should not be longer than a printed A4. And if you are having that many variables in one function it is probably also better to refactor your code to create more smaller functions..

Comment: @DaanTimmer, I agree long function should be break into small one. But a function doesn't need A4 length to have 10 variables. In legacy C language code, function is typically longer than A4. It is not reasonable to expect all function is shorter than A4 in realistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say your compiler doesn't support exceptions. But does it support executing destructors on early return? I sure hope it does. You should make sure with a simple test.

Which means you can just use smart pointers and other classes that release resources in the destructor.

```
int res = callAPI1();
if (!res) return -1;
scoped_ptr<A> object1(callAPI2());
if (!object1) return -1;
scoped_ptr<C> object2(callAPI3(object1.get()));
if ((!object2) return -1;
return 0;
```

`scoped_ptr` here could be any suitable smart pointer class: your compiler's `unique_ptr` in the unlikely case is supports it, `auto_ptr` if you're feeling brave, `boost::scoped_ptr` if you can use Boost, or just write your own `scoped_ptr`, it's pretty trivial.

```
template <typename T>
class scoped_ptr {
  T* raw;

  struct bool_dummy { void fn() {} };
  typedef void (bool_dummy::*pseudo_bool)();

  scoped_ptr(const scoped_ptr&); // non-copyable
  scoped_ptr& operator =(const scoped_ptr&);

public:
  scoped_ptr(T* raw) : raw(raw) {}
  ~scoped_ptr() { delete raw; }

  T* get() const { return raw; }
  T& operator *() const { return *get(); }
  T* operator ->() const { return get(); }
  operator pseudo_bool() const { return get() ? &bool_dummy::fn : 0; }
  bool operator !() const { return !get(); }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that resolve most my case, I even thought this is mission impossible :) . I will mark this as answer, even this solution is not always possible if the cleanup code is complex.

Comment: If you have complex cleanup code, you may have to write a custom cleanup class, but it is *always* possible to use RAII.

Comment: here's a nice article showing just that: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/generic-change-the-way-you-write-excepti/184403758

Answer (score 0):

I like to do it like this:

```
int foo()
{
  A* object1 = 0; // make sure you initialize those two
  C* object2 = 0; // so that further delete calls always work

  for (;;)
  {
    int res = callAPI1();
    if (res == -1)
      break;

    object1 = callAPI2();
    if (object1 == 0)
      break;

    object2 = callAPI3(object1);
    if (object2 == 0)
      break;

    return 0;
  }

  delete object1;
  delete object2;

  return -1;
}
```

However, it's not always possible to articulate the code like above. But when it is, I find it great. It has the advantage of placing (just like a `goto`) the cleanup code in a single place. Otherwise it could become unmaintainable like:

```
// don't do this:
if(object2==0)
{
  delete object1;
  return 0;
}
// ... more code ...
if(object3==0)
{
  delete object2;
  delete object1;
  return 0;
}
// ... more code ...
if(object4==0)
{
  delete object3
  delete object2;
  delete object1;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm the OP explicit wanted it without initialisazion of A and B.

Comment: I know this is subjective, but this `for+break` just looks weird to me. At least `goto cleanup` conveys a clear message - and can be easily used with more complex code.

Answer (score 0):

Right, not the most beatiful code but it will do:

```
int res = callAPI1();
if (!res) /* inverse of CHECK_ERROR_GOTO(res, cleanup); ??? */
{
    A * object1 = callAPI2();

    if (object1 != null) /* inverse of CHECK_ERROR_GOTO(object1 == NULL, cleanup); */
    {
        C * object2 = callAPI3(object1); //I suppose you want object1 here and not 2

        if (object2 != null) /* inverse of CHECK_ERROR_GOTO(object2 == NULL, cleanup);*/
        {
            /* if we reached here then both object1 and 2 are created
               thus delete both before returning to not get any memory leaks */
            delete object1;
            delete object2;

            return 0;
        }

        /* if we reached here then the creation of object2 has failed.
           Only delete object1 because object2 is not initialized. */
        delete object1;

        /* do some kind of return here? like -3 */
    }


    /* do some kind of return here? like -2 */
}

/* do some kind of return here? like -1*/
```